# backbone + layoutmanager (backbone-boilerplate) collection empty in beforeRender

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-boilerplate, backbone-layout-manager

I working on a project to test this backbone-boilerplate (https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate) but i have a problem to render a view. 
I have the first call to beforeRender, the collection (pics) is empty because the fetching of Flickr photos is still in progress.
But when the data are loaded, i can see them in the "parse" function of my Pics.Collection (with a breakpoint), the beforeRender of my view is never called again.

My router.js :

```
 define([
    // Application.
    "app",

    "modules/pics"
],

function(app, HomePage, Pics) {

    // Defining the application router, you can attach sub routers here.
    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            // Init collections
            var collections = {
                pics: new Pics.Collection()
            };
            console.log('collec');
            // Register in the router
            _.extend(this, collections);
        },

        routes: {
            "": "pics"
        },

        pics: function() {
            this.reset();

            app.useLayout().setViews({
                "#content": new Pics.Views.List({ pics: this.pics }),
                "header": new Backbone.View({
                    tagName: "span",
                    beforeRender: function() {
                        this.$el.html("Header Pics");
                    }
                })
            }).render();

            this.pics.fetch();
        },

        reset: function() {
            if (this.pics.length) {
                this.pics.reset();
            }
        }
    });

  return Router;

});
```

My module, pics.js :

```
define([
    "app"
], function(app) {

    var Pics = app.module();

    Pics.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({ });

    Pics.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Pics.Model,
        url: function() {
            return "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=?";
        },
        cache: true,
        parse: function(obj) {
            return obj.items;
        }
    });

    Pics.Views.Item = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: "pics/item",
        tagName: "li",

        serialize: function() {
            return { model: this.model };
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        }
    });

    Pics.Views.List = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: "pics/list",

        serialize: function() {
            return { collection: this.options.pics };
        },

        beforeRender: function() {
            this.options.pics.each(function(pic) {
                this.insertView("#pics-list", new Pics.Views.Item({
                    model: pic
                }));
            }, this);
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.options.pics, {
                "reset": this.render(),
                "request": function() {
                    this.$("ul").parent().html("<img src='/app/img/spinner-gray.gif'>");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return Pics;
});
```

list.html (template) :

```
<h1>Liste des photos</h1>
<div>
    <div class="loading"></div>
    <ul id="pics-list"></ul>
</div>
```

item.html (template) :

```
<li>
    <img src="<%= model.get("link") %>" />
</li>
```

index.html :

```
<main role="main" id="main">

      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
      <header></header>
      <aside></aside>
      <section id="content"></section>
      <footer>
          Copyright 2013
      </footer>

  </main>
```

I search if an existing issue exists, on forums and by myself since two days but i can't find what is going wrong.

Thanks in advance, Pierrick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, listen the "sync" event instead of "change".